# Transitioning from Firefox add-on to WebExtensions: add-on version updates on older Firefox versions

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

We have a Firefox extension that was recently ported from the Firefox add-ons architecture to the "new" WebExtensions architecture, however, we have a couple problems:

1. There is a bug that prevents our extension from working in FF49 using WebExtensions.
2. We want to keep support for the old add-ons version on https://addons.mozilla.org to support customers using older versions of Firefox, including Firefox ESR, but also want to make the WebExtensions version available to those that prefer the latest and greatest browser version.

My question is: Can I have multiple versions of our extension available on http://addons.mozilla.org/ that are supported for specific versions of Firefox? i.e., Version 1 of our extension supports FF <= 49; version 2 supports FF >= 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple versions of your add-on available which are compatible with specified ranges of Firefox versions.  This capability has existed for years.

Within your *manifest.json* file you can specify a [`strict_min_version`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications):

```
"applications": {
  "gecko": {
    "id": "addon@example.com",
    "strict_min_version": "42.0",
    "strict_max_version": "50.*",
    "update_url": "https://example.com/updates.json"
  }
}
```

However, that *manifest.json* key requires Firefox 45 (for WebExtensions). Specifying a minimum and maximum version for the application has been available for years for other types of add-ons. You will also need to manually manage the maximum compatible Firefox version for each version of your add-on from [AMO Developer Hub](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addons).

On AMO Developer Hub, in the control panel for your add-on, select "Manage Status & Versions" (bottom option in top section of the colored left menu list):
[image: AMO Menu selection]

On the page shown when you select "Manage Status & Versions", select the version you are concerned about.

On the page for each version of your add-on, you can change the Firefox versions with which the selected version of your add-on is compatible:
[image: AMO Firefox version compatibility]

Note: While it is my experience that version compatibility selections will affect which version of your add-on is installed automatically, setting the maximum version will not prevent users from being offered to install, and installing, the *most recent version* of your add-on in versions of Firefox which are later than the maximum version specified for the most recent version of your add-on. In addition, AMO will automatically increase the maximum Firefox version of the most recent version of your add-on based on automated testing, even if you have manually set the maximum version.

However, in other types of add-ons, this should be able to be controlled via the [`strictCompatibility` entry in *install.rdf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#strictCompatibility).  In my case, I was not aware of the incompatibility with a future version of Firefox at the time the add-on version was uploaded (prior to the incompatible version of Firefox existing). Thus, I had not set that option in my *install.rdf*. For a WebExtension, this should be able to be controlled with the `strict_max_version` key in your *manifest.json*.

If you have a newer version of your add-on uploaded to AMO, you should not need to worry about this.  The version of your add-on which is compatible with the version of Firefox being run by the user, based on the information contained in the add-on's *.xpi* and/or as specified by you in the AMO Developer Hub control panel for each version, should be automatically selected for download and installation. New versions of your add-on which are declared as not compatible with an older version of Firefox should not be used for automatic upgrades.

**Side note on transitioning data:**
You should consider releasing *at least* one version of your add-on which uses an [Embedded WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Embedded_WebExtensions) to be able to transition any data you have stored in the old add-on version to WebExtensions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have specific experience of updating an SDK addon with a WebExtensions version? Are there specific roadblocks / migration tips on that?

Comment: I have not yet attempted to update an add-on to WebExtensions. All of my public add-ons use capabilities which do not, and probably will not, exist in WebExtensions. Thus, my WebExtensions experience currently only includes some as yet unreleased add-ons (probably, eventually released), and 40-50, or so, smaller test extensions created for testing and/or to answer questions here. I do, however, have a public non-WebExtension add-on that is very tied to exact versions of Firefox. It must be updated for many, but not all, new versions of Firefox. Thus, I have dealt with version update issues.

Comment: I think this upgrade path warrants a test, and I don't have an AMO account yet to do it..

Comment: @Xan, I agree, a test to confirm it works specifically with WebExtensions is a good idea. It is always possible that there are bugs in the code added for interpreting WebExtensions. However, the capability has existed for quite some time, for other types of add-ons. There have been multiple potentially breaking changes in Firefox releases over the last few years where the capability has been needed for many add-ons. My lack of testing was a primary reason to also mention that the min/max version should *also* be specified via the AMO Developer Hub UI, which I have used/tested.